# C# switch syntax error

Tags: c#, switch-statement, syntax-error

I have this switch statement to test the case of my Grounded integer variable but my Unity-Monodevelop says I have weird syntax errors within my code which I can't find. I am hoping someone can tell me what is wrong with it.

```
private void JumpController () {
    if (Input.GetAxis("Jump")) { // if jump switch to action
        switch (Grounded) {
        0:  // On ground;
            Jump ();
            Grounded = 1;
            break;
        1:  // Jumped once;
            Jump ();
            Grounded = 2;
            break;
        2:  // Jumped twice;
            Debug.print ("Grounded = 2");
            break;
        default: break; 
        }
    }
}
```

[An Image showing the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0FmN.png)

Comment: case x:? ......

Comment: You're missing the `case` keyword. e.g, `case 0: Jump();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend adding a `case` before your cases. This should fix the errors:

```
private void JumpController () {
    if (Input.GetAxis("Jump")) { // if jump switch to action
        switch (Grounded) {
        case 0:  // On ground;
            Jump ();
            Grounded = 1;
            break;
        case 1:  // Jumped once;
            Jump ();
            Grounded = 2;
            break;
        case 2:  // Jumped twice;
            Debug.print ("Grounded = 2");
            break;
        default: break; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I can't believe I missed that even the structure guide I was using had them but I just overlooked them. Fixing this error I finally got the real errors which is my if statement.

Comment: Mind marking the answer as correct then? It makes it easier for other people to find answers.

Comment: Sure thing. I hope I did it right- this site is kinda confusing to use for the first time as an actual user and not just from google reference.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the case keyword for each case. E.g.:

```
switch (Grounded) {
    case 0 :
    // something
    break;

}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/06tc147t.aspx